# MYSQL Trigger syntax issue

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying this trigger but it keeps giving me this error:

**Trigger**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
TRIGGER entries_limit_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON Feed
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
Set @counts=(SELECT count(*) from Feed);
IF (@counts > 10000)
THEN
PRINT 'INSERTED SUCCESS';
END IF; 
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Error**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''INSERTED SUCCESS'; END IF; END' at line 9
```

Comment: I don't think MySQL has a `PRINT`

Comment: The error is for sure in your PRINT. What do you want to do with that? You want to cancel the insert? want to do something with counts?

Comment: PRINT? MySQL is a server not a terminal. Also, you are counting the records BEFORE an insert on your feed table.  Why?  Wouldn't you count the records AFTER the insert to determine if it was a success? Rethink the purpose of this trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the trigger to exit with a message you can do:

```
CREATE
TRIGGER entries_limit_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON Feed
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
Set @counts=(SELECT count(*) from Feed);
IF @counts > 10000 THEN
  set @msg = "Reached the limit";
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @msg;
END IF; 
END;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73908)</kbd>

To make it exit with a message, just add another insert to the fiddle.